# Match second date in a string

Tags: regex, excel, vba, email, outlook

Could you please advise regarding a VBA script for matching the date format below in email.

> Start: 23.06.2017  00:00:00 (CEST) **22.06.2017 22:00 (GMT)**

Note: There is another date. I need only match the bold to export it into Excel.

```
Set SD = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

With SD.Pattern = "((Start:*\s*\s*[\d-\.]*\s*\s*\s*[\d-\.]*))"
    .Global = False
    .IgnoreCase = False
End With

If SD.test(sText) Then
    Set D1 = SD.Execute(sText)
    For Each D In D1
        vText1 = Trim(D.SubMatches(1))
    Next
End If
xlSheet.Range("C" & rCount) = vText1
```

Comment: so you didnt other trying anything at all?

Comment: hello, how can i add my code? its too long please advise?

Comment: see [mcve] and [ask]

Comment: could you please advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this Regex:  `[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}(?=\s\(GMT\))`

Here is a working example.  [RegexStorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b0-9%5d%7b2%7d%5c.%5b0-9%5d%7b2%7d%5c.%5b0-9%5d%7b4%7d%5cs%5b0-9%5d%7b2%7d%5c%3a%5b0-9%5d%7b2%7d%28%3f%3d%5cs%5c%28GMT%5c%29%29&i=Start%3a+23.06.2017+00%3a00%3a00+%28CEST%29+22.06.2017+22%3a00+%28GMT%29+End%3a+23.06.2017+05%3a00%3a00+%28CEST%29+23.06.2017+03%3a00+%28GMT%29+)

The first part is the sets of numbers, the last part says that it must be followed by a space and (GMT).

Here is a link to a VB.Net example to get both date/time strings.  You will need to convert that to VBA.

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dV81ba)

Comment: many thanks, but how to get second occurrence as below for end date:
Start: 23.06.2017  00:00:00 (CEST) 22.06.2017 22:00 (GMT)
End:   23.06.2017  05:00:00 (CEST) 23.06.2017 03:00 (GMT)
appreciated :)

Comment: It will capture both date/times.  You will need to access the capture groups.  There will be two.  Click the updated RegexStorm link and then click the table tab at the bottom to see how it gets both matches.

Comment: thanks again, sorry but still i can get the 1st only please see the code:

if SD.test(sText) Then
 Set D1 = SD.Execute(sText)
 For Each D In D1
 vText1 = Trim(D.SubMatches(0))
 vText2 = Trim(D.SubMatches(1))
 Next
 End If
 xlSheet.Range("C" & rCount) = vText1
  xlSheet.Range("D" & rCount) = vText2